# Python series is ambiguous in data frame error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the dataframe and using this I am doing logical operation which throws error as follows. How can I overcome this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    in <module>
    if( eoddf['High'][Open] > linebreakvalue):
  File "", line , in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

logic is below the table :

eoddf: (dataframe)

```
           Symbol Series  Prev Close    Open    High     Low    Last   Close  \
Date                                                                           
2015-01-01   SBIN     EQ      311.85  312.45  315.00  310.70  314.00  314.00   
2015-01-02   SBIN     EQ      314.00  314.35  318.30  314.35  315.60  315.25   
2015-01-05   SBIN     EQ      315.25  316.25  316.80  312.10  312.80  312.75   
2015-01-06   SBIN     EQ      312.75  310.00  311.10  298.70  299.90  299.90   
2015-01-07   SBIN     EQ      299.90  300.00  302.55  295.15  301.40  300.15   
2015-01-08   SBIN     EQ      300.15  305.00  306.50  302.35  305.25  304.85   
2015-01-09   SBIN     EQ      304.85  306.70  307.85  302.00  303.00  303.20   
2015-01-12   SBIN     EQ      303.20  304.15  307.80  301.10  306.90  307.10   
2015-01-13   SBIN     EQ      307.10  308.15  310.75  304.15  305.25  305.10   
2015-01-14   SBIN     EQ      305.10  304.00  307.00  302.25  305.00  304.70   
2015-01-15   SBIN     EQ      304.70  319.90  323.70  314.00  318.40  320.30   
2015-01-16   SBIN     EQ      320.30  320.00  320.30  313.10  315.25  315.45   
2015-01-19   SBIN     EQ      315.45  316.55  317.95  312.50  313.20  313.15   
2015-01-20   SBIN     EQ      313.15  314.00  319.80  314.00  318.00  318.15   
2015-01-21   SBIN     EQ      318.15  319.90  327.60  319.00  326.00  326.20   
2015-01-22   SBIN     EQ      326.20  326.90  327.60  321.80  325.20  324.65   
2015-01-23   SBIN     EQ      324.65  328.25  332.55  324.65  327.05  327.45   
2015-01-27   SBIN     EQ      327.45  329.40  332.15  322.60  331.45  330.05   
2015-01-28   SBIN     EQ      330.05  330.40  336.00  328.20  333.40  334.60
```

Code:

```
 for Open in range(1, len(eoddf)):
     if( eoddf['High'][Open] > linebreakvalue):
        eoddf['LBHigh']{Open]=eoddf['High'][Open]
        eoddf['LBLow'][Open] =eoddf['Low'][Open]
        linebreakvalue = eoddf['LBHigh'][Open]
     if( eoddf['Low'][Open] < linebreakvalue):
        eoddf['LBHigh'][Open]=eoddf['Low'][Open]
        eoddf['LBLow'][Open] =eoddf['High'][Open]
        linebreakvalue = eoddf['LBLow'][Open]
```

I am trying to write this MQ4 code to Python for my need. The code reference is here: http://www.35pip.com/metatrader-indicators/indicators/3LineBreak.mq4

Also I wanted to run this loop till the last entry of Open column any better for loop or some other method can be used here?

Basically I am trying to convert this piece of code to Python

```
OLDSwing=Swing;
VALUE1=High[Highest(NULL,0,MODE_HIGH,Lines_Break,shift+1)];
VALUE2= Low[Lowest(NULL,0,MODE_LOW,Lines_Break,shift+1)];
if (OLDSwing==1 &&  Low[shift]<VALUE2) Swing=-1;
if (OLDSwing==-1 && High[shift]>VALUE1 ) Swing=1;
if (Swing==1) 
   { HighBuffer[shift]=High[shift]; LowBuffer[shift]=Low[shift]; }
if (Swing==-1)
{ LowBuffer[shift]=High[shift]; HighBuffer[shift]=Low[shift]; }
```

And the rules for this is:

- If the price exceeds the previous line's high price, a new green line is drawn
- If the price falls below the previous line's low price, a new red line is drawn
- If the price does not rise above nor fall below the previous line, nothing is drawn
- If a rally is powerful enough to form three consecutive green lines, then a new red line is drawn only if price fall below the lowest point of the last three green lines
- If a sell-off is powerful enough to form three consecutive red lines, then a new green line is drawn only if price rise above the highest point of the last three red lines.

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you seek:

```
eoddf['LBHigh'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['High'] if x['High'] > linebreakvalue else x['Low'], axis=1)
eoddf['LBLow'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Low'] if x['Low'] < linebreakvalue else x['High'], axis=1)
```

Comment: same error  Traceback (most recent call last):

    results[i] = func(v)
  File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\nsepy\testplot.py", line 413, in <lambda>
    eoddf['LBHigh'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['High'] if x['High'] > linebreakvalue else x['Low'], axis=1)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 953, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 2017-10-03')

Comment: This solution is not using `for` loop so you might want to drop that part.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need double [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but condition return second value if equality:

```
linebreakvalue = 320
m1 = eoddf['High'] > linebreakvalue
m2 = eoddf['Low'] > linebreakvalue

eoddf['LBHigh']= np.where(m1, eoddf['High'], eoddf['Low'])
eoddf['LBLow'] = np.where(m2, eoddf['Low'], eoddf['High'])
```

---

```
print (eoddf)

           Symbol Series  Prev Close    Open    High     Low    Last   Close  \
2015-01-01   SBIN     EQ      311.85  312.45  315.00  310.70  314.00  314.00   
2015-01-02   SBIN     EQ      314.00  314.35  318.30  314.35  315.60  315.25   
2015-01-05   SBIN     EQ      315.25  316.25  316.80  312.10  312.80  312.75   
2015-01-06   SBIN     EQ      312.75  310.00  311.10  298.70  299.90  299.90   
2015-01-07   SBIN     EQ      299.90  300.00  302.55  295.15  301.40  300.15   
2015-01-08   SBIN     EQ      300.15  305.00  306.50  302.35  305.25  304.85   
2015-01-09   SBIN     EQ      304.85  306.70  307.85  302.00  303.00  303.20   
2015-01-12   SBIN     EQ      303.20  304.15  307.80  301.10  306.90  307.10   
2015-01-13   SBIN     EQ      307.10  308.15  310.75  304.15  305.25  305.10   
2015-01-14   SBIN     EQ      305.10  304.00  307.00  302.25  305.00  304.70   
2015-01-15   SBIN     EQ      304.70  319.90  323.70  314.00  318.40  320.30   
2015-01-16   SBIN     EQ      320.30  320.00  320.30  313.10  315.25  315.45   
2015-01-19   SBIN     EQ      315.45  316.55  317.95  312.50  313.20  313.15   
2015-01-20   SBIN     EQ      313.15  314.00  319.80  314.00  318.00  318.15   
2015-01-21   SBIN     EQ      318.15  319.90  327.60  319.00  326.00  326.20   
2015-01-22   SBIN     EQ      326.20  326.90  327.60  321.80  325.20  324.65   
2015-01-23   SBIN     EQ      324.65  328.25  332.55  324.65  327.05  327.45   
2015-01-27   SBIN     EQ      327.45  329.40  332.15  322.60  331.45  330.05   
2015-01-28   SBIN     EQ      330.05  330.40  336.00  328.20  333.40  334.60   

            LBHigh   LBLow  
2015-01-01  310.70  315.00  
2015-01-02  314.35  318.30  
2015-01-05  312.10  316.80  
2015-01-06  298.70  311.10  
2015-01-07  295.15  302.55  
2015-01-08  302.35  306.50  
2015-01-09  302.00  307.85  
2015-01-12  301.10  307.80  
2015-01-13  304.15  310.75  
2015-01-14  302.25  307.00  
2015-01-15  323.70  323.70  
2015-01-16  320.30  320.30  
2015-01-19  312.50  317.95  
2015-01-20  314.00  319.80  
2015-01-21  327.60  327.60  
2015-01-22  327.60  321.80  
2015-01-23  332.55  324.65  
2015-01-27  332.15  322.60  
2015-01-28  336.00  328.20
```

But if really need loops:

```
for i, x in eoddf.iterrows():
    if(eoddf.loc[i, 'High'] > linebreakvalue):
       eoddf.loc[i, 'LBHigh']=eoddf.loc[i,'High']
       eoddf.loc[i,'LBLow'] =eoddf.loc[i,'Low']
    if(eoddf.loc[i,'Low'] < linebreakvalue):
       eoddf.loc[i,'LBHigh']=eoddf.loc[i,'Low']
       eoddf.loc[i,'LBLow'] =eoddf.loc[i,'High']
```

Comment: changing < to <= throws still the error. this is the original mq4 code that i try to make it in python ;if solution to this also fine OLDSwing=Swing;
    VALUE1=High[Highest(NULL,0,MODE_HIGH,Lines_Break,shift+1)];
    VALUE2= Low[Lowest(NULL,0,MODE_LOW,Lines_Break,shift+1)];
    if (OLDSwing==1 &&  Low[shift]<VALUE2) Swing=-1;
    if (OLDSwing==-1 && High[shift]>VALUE1 ) Swing=1;
    if (Swing==1) 
       { HighBuffer[shift]=High[shift]; LowBuffer[shift]=Low[shift]; }
    if (Swing==-1)
    { LowBuffer[shift]=High[shift]; HighBuffer[shift]=Low[shift]; }

Comment: I check it and it working nice - maybe problem is my solution is same as your for loop in question and your original code is different :(

Comment: I try rewrite your loop to vectorize operations.  Can you add your not working code from comment to answer because bad formating? Also if your loop does not work, is possible add expected output from your sample data?

Comment: The output is something like this Blue and Red Line Just below to Candles Formed using LOW and HIGH price as shown in the figure of this link .Once dataframe with this output is ready i will make chart using plotly. https://www.mql5.com/en/code/1298